# Navigation component with viewpager performance issues

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

My situation is the following: I have a `HomeFragment` which contains a `ViewPager` that has 3 Fragments (one of those has a child Fragment aswell). When I now navigate away from the `HomeFragment` and try to go back, the transition takes 1-2 seconds and is very laggy, probably because all 3 Fragments inside the `Viewpager` get restored. Is there a cleaner way to do this with the Android `Navigation Component`?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using FragmentPagerAdapter instead of FragmentStatePagerAdapter

From the documentation:

**FragmentPagerAdapter** - Use this when navigating between a fixed, small number of sibling screens.

**FragmentStatePagerAdapter** - Use this when paging across an unknown number of pages. FragmentStatePagerAdapter optimizes memory usage by **destroying fragments as the user navigates away**.

Also try to use ConstraintLayout where you can to keep your view hierarchy flat.
In this video the speaker explains why that is important: 
https://youtu.be/rzmB3UxxhaA?t=2188